# Get JSON object from the list of array based on line number

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, logic

I am doing my development in intellij idea. Here my requirement is i have a json file open in the editor, and my cursor is on particular line. I am able to find line number, now my next task is to, fetch the entire object from the json file (its an array of objects), where my cursor is. For example this is my json.

```
[{
        "facility": "Global",
        "group_names": [
            "H R"
        ],
        "group_type": "department",
        "remove_users_on_logout": false,
        "shift_membership": {
            "min": 50,
            "max": 50,
            "source": "any_shift",
            "type": [
                "auxiliary"
            ]
        },
        "child_members": [{
            "diamond": {
                "diamond_id": "akron_hr"
            }
        }]
    },
    {
        "facility": "Global",
        "group_names": [
            "I T"
        ],
        "group_type": "department",
        "remove_users_on_logout": false,
        "shift_membership": {
            "min": 40,
            "max": 40,
            "source": "per_shift",
            "type": [
                "auxiliary"
            ]
        },
        "child_members": [{
                "diamond": {
                    "diamond_id": "akron_it"
                }
            },
            {
                "diamond": {
                    "diamond_id": "baltimore_it"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

for example if i am on any line starting from 1 to 21 my output should be,

```
{
        "facility": "Global",
        "group_names": [
            "H R"
        ],
        "group_type": "department",
        "remove_users_on_logout": false,
        "shift_membership": {
            "min": 50,
            "max": 50,
            "source": "any_shift",
            "type": [
                "auxiliary"
            ]
        },
        "child_members": [{
            "diamond": {
                "diamond_id": "akron_hr"
            }
        }]
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what approach can help me? Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What framework do you use for parsing JSON? Jackson, GSON, something else?

Comment: i am using GSON framework for parsing JSON

Comment: I guess the requirement is just wrong for several reasons: 1) JSON is not a line-oriented format (especially, it does not dictate a strict formatting convention), so line numbers are not supposed to be used for navigation: there are JSON navigation DSLs like those used in JsonPath or `jq` that can point to a JSON element; 2) the term of "entire object" in conjunction with line numbers doesn't play well: how deep/nested the target JSON element is supposed to be so that you could tell which you would like to pick up?

Comment: Compare "try to guess what's within lines 1 and 21, assuming it was not re-formatted" with `jq '.[0]' < input.json` (using `jq`) or, if I'm not mistaken about JsonPath, `$[0]`. Aside, you'd be able to use filters, not simply "the first element" in case of necessity. And it would work even if your JSON documents are minified.

Comment: Hey @fluffy, I totally agree with you, going by line number can make my life hell. Is it possible for you to share how can i extract entire object  from an array, i didnt understood, how can JSON navigation DSLs help me. Please share something in detail. It would be great if you can assist me, as i have spent more than a week, and still dont have required solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnkitOstwal I'm not saying that JSON navigation languages are here to let you address your JSON elements by lines. They don't, and it would make very little sense if any. What I'm talking about is: do not use line numbers for this at all, revise your approach, whatever, but don't use line numbers. That's it.

Comment: Hey @fluffy, my goal is to fetch the json object from an json array. Condition here is, if there is a cursor on any line, that entire object should be fetched. I dont have any information about that node.Can you suggest any approach for this? Line number is definitely, not a good approach, i agree with you.Help is appreciated. Thanks.